# How to create a next.js app directly in the current folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How I can create next-app in the current folder?

I tried:

```
npx create-next-app@latest .  --ts --use-npm
```

But I get error:

```
Could not create a project called "folderName" because of npm naming restrictions:
 * name can no longer contain capital letters
```

Comment: The error message seems to clearly state what is wrong.  `name can no longer contain capital letters`. Try changing the name of the folder from "folderName" to "foldername" & try.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you are using linux or mac try this

`npx create-next-app@latest ./  --ts --use-npm`

it is working for me on both linux and mac

Comment: Also works with `pnpm create next-app ./`

Answer (score 4):

For **Windows** users use `npx create-next-app@latest ./`

**Note:** Your existing folder name can't contain any uppercase characters. *Ex: BookStore can be ==> bookstore or book_store*